# Dispatch action error, cannot read props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to dispatch an action to show a modal.

I get the error cannot read props of null.

```
    <div className="cell">
                <button onClick={this.openAchievementModal} className="modal-button">+ Add Achievement</button>
    </div>
```

Click handler:

```
openAchievementModal(){
    this.props.showModal({
      type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
      modalType: 'DELETE_POST',
      modalProps: {
        postId: 42
    }
  })
}
```

Any ideas how I dispatch my action with props?

UPDATE: I have 2 reducers, one to manage my data:

```
import {ADD_ACHIEVEMENT, ADD_ENJOYMENT } from '../constants/ActionTypes'

const initialState = [
  {
    date: "Fri 1st",
    enjoyments: [],
    achievements: [],
    id: 0
  },
  {
    date: "Sat 2nd",
    enjoyments: ['Football', 'Rugby'],
    achievements: ['Tennis', 'Football'],
    id: 1
  },
  { 
    date: "Sun 3rd",
    enjoyments: [],
    achievements: [],
    id: 2
  },
  {
    date: "Mon 4th",
    enjoyments: [],
    achievements: [],
    id:3
  },
  {
    date: "Tue 5th",
    enjoyments: [],
    achievements: [],
    id: 4
  },
  "isOpen": false
]

export default function days(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

   case ADD_ACHIEVEMENT:
      return state.map(item => {
          if (item.id === action.id) {
              return Object.assign({}, item, {
                achievements: [
                ...item.achievements,
                action.text,
                ]
              });
          }

        return item;
    });
    case ADD_ENJOYMENT:
      return state.map(item => {
        if (item.id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, item, {
            enjoyments: [
              ...item.enjoyments,
              action.text,
            ]
          });
        }

        return item;
    });
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The other to manage my modals:

```
import {SHOW_MODAL, HIDE_MODAL } from '../constants/ActionTypes'


import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../actions';

import AddAchievementModal from '../components/modals/AddAchievementModal.js';
import RemoveAchievementModal from '../components/modals/RemoveAchievementModal.js';

const initialState = {
  modalType: null,
  modalProps: {}
}


function modal(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_MODAL':
      return {
        modalType: action.modalType,
        modalProps: action.modalProps
      }
    case 'HIDE_MODAL':
      return initialState
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In my container component I Have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../actions'

class Achievement extends Component {

  openAchievementModal(){
        this.props.showModal({
          type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
          modalType: 'DELETE_POST',
          modalProps: {
            postId: 42
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
        var options = [
          { value: 1, label: 'Play Music' },
          { value: 2, label: 'Football' }
        ];

    let listItems

    if(this.props.day.achievements) {
       listItems = this.props.day.achievements.map((achievement) => (
           <div className="cell" key={achievement + "_achievements"}>
             {achievement}
         <button onClick={this.openRemoveModal} className="modal-button">+ remove Achievement</button>
           </div>
       ))
    }

    return (
         <span key={this.props.day + "span"}>
                {listItems}

                <div className="cell">
                    <button onClick={this.openAchievementModal} className="modal-button">+ Add Achievement</button>
                </div>

      </span>
    )

    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    days: state.days
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Achievement);
```

My ModelRoot component:

```
import AddAchievementModal from '../components/modals/AddAchievementModal.js';
import RemoveAchievementModal from '../components/modals/RemoveAchievementModal.js';

const MODAL_COMPONENTS = {
  'REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT': RemoveAchievementModal,
  'ADD_ACHIEVEMENT': AddAchievementModal,
  /* other modals */
}

const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps }) => {
  if (!modalType) {
    return <span /> // after React v15 you can return null here
  }

  const SpecificModal = MODAL_COMPONENTS[modalType]
  return <SpecificModal {...modalProps} />
}

export default connect(
  state => state.modal
)(ModalRoot)
```

Comment: Show the whole component's code, it's hard to tell from sample you have provided... Is your redux configured properly, actions, and reducers are working in another component's or it;s first try and the problem may be that your redux configuration is not correct yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `openAchievementModal` is not bound to the component instance as class methods are not bound by default in JavaScript. Please bind it manually in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.openAchievementModal = this.openAchievementModal.bind(this)
}
```

Or in the render function:

```
<button onClick={this.openAchievementModal.bind(this)} ... />
```

You may also use arrow function syntax to preserve lexical this (as suggested by [bzekiunat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44241639/1384679)):

```
<button onClick={() => { this.openAchievementModal() } } ... />
```

Or if you transpile your code already, use [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and arrow functions (note `= () =>` instead of `()`):

```
openAchievementModal = () => {
  this.props.showModal({
    type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
    modalType: 'DELETE_POST',
    modalProps: {
      postId: 42
    }
  })
}
```

Final code:

```
class Achievement extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.openAchievementModal = this.openAchievementModal.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <button onClick={this.openAchievementModal} className="modal-button">+ Add Achievement</button>
    ...
  }
}
```

---

Please see following examples for different binding methods:

```js
class ConstructorBoundExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.openAchievementModal = this.openAchievementModal.bind(this)
  }
  
  openAchievementModal() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.openModal("test")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.openAchievementModal} className="modal-button">Constructor bound - works</button>
    )
  }
}

class InlineBoundExample extends React.Component {
  openAchievementModal() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.openModal("test")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.openAchievementModal.bind(this)} className="modal-button">Inline bound - works</button>
    )
  }
}

class FunctionBoundExample extends React.Component {
  openAchievementModal() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.openModal("test")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={function() { console.log(this.props); this.openAchievementModal() }} className="modal-button">Function bound - does not work - and should not</button>
    )
  }
}

class ArrowBoundExample extends React.Component {
  openAchievementModal() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.openModal("test")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => { console.log(this.props); this.openAchievementModal() }} className="modal-button">Arrow bound - works</button>
    )
  }
}

class ES7ClassPropertyBoundExample extends React.Component {
  openAchievementModal = () => {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.openModal("test")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => { console.log(this.props); this.openAchievementModal() }} className="modal-button">ES7 class property bound - works</button>
    )
  }
}

const openModal = message => {
  alert(message)
}

class Examples extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ConstructorBoundExample openModal={openModal} />
        <InlineBoundExample openModal={openModal} />
        <FunctionBoundExample openModal={openModal} />
        <ArrowBoundExample openModal={openModal} />
        <ES7ClassPropertyBoundExample openModal={openModal} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Examples />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `bind` for some reason, you can wrap `this.openAchievementModal` function.

```
<div className="cell">
     <button onClick={() => this.openAchievementModal()} className="modal-button">+ Add Achievement</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work as `this` still will not be bound in `openAchievementModal`. He may to pass the `showModal` as an parameter, then just use the method you described above `onClick={() => this.openAchievementModal(this.props.showModal)}` with `openAchievementModal(showModal){ showModal(...) }`.

Comment: If I used `function`, you were right. Like this;

     `onClick={function() { this.openAchievementModal(this.props.showModal)}`
Using arrow function makes it work.

Comment: I was really wrong, you are absolutely right. Arrow functions preserve lexical this and it is valid when calling `openAchievementModal`. Please see [following example with different options of binding](https://jsfiddle.net/99nmd67p/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `showModal` defined anywhere. And as far as I understand, `showModal` has to dispatch an action. So, you have to pass a second parameter to your `connect` function: `mapDispatchToProps`

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    showModal() {
      dispatch(
        type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
        modalType: 'DELETE_POST',
        modalProps: {
          postId: 42
        }
      )
    }   
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Achievement)
```

And after that you just need to call `this.props.showModal()` inside your function `openAchievementModal`

EDIT: I see that `postId` is hardcoded, you might want to consider to pass the value as parameter of the function `showModal`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know how I can add my modelRoot to my app to display the appropriate modal?

Comment: I see you already do it inside your code, are you looking for a more elegant way? I think it's OK right now. You could render it at bottom of your DOM, hidden (you can actually return null as pointed by your comment). When you can the proper action, your component will render and will have proper styles to cover the main screen.